# Avoid using if else statement on returning two methods

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way that I can avoid using an if/else statement in this situation?

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $m = $request->query('m', 'a');

    if ($m === 'a') {
        $this->test();
    } else if ($m === 'b') {
        $this->r($m);
    }
}

public function r($m)
{
    echo 'Hello!';
}
```

I'd like to return the `import()` method on `$mode = update`, but if it's `refresh` to use the refresh method.

Is there a cleaner way to approach this?

Comment: do you mind using the ternary operator as well? it would be cleaner but logically the same

Comment: Not at all @UzairRiaz, do you have an example?

Comment: I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the ternary operator if you know you will get only 2 of those inputs everytime:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $m = $request->query('m', 'a');

    $m === 'a' ? $this->test() : $this->r($m);
}
```

Comment: This ended up working well! Thanks @Uzair - Sorry for the late response, would you please upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are having multiple conditions to check and based on them you have to call the function. just use this technique:

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $m = $request->query('m', 'a');
    $method = 'useQueryFor' . $m;
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
       return $this->{$method}();
    }
}

public function useQueryFora(){
    echo 'used query for a.';
}

public function useQueryForb(){
    echo 'used query for b.';
}
```

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thank yo so much for this.